# How to get Foursquare's venues/explore endpoint on C# with Sharpsquare

Tags: c#, foursquare, sharpsquare

I'm using Sharpsquare to make API requests to Foursquare endpoints.

I can call, for example `venues/trending` with no problem. However, I couldn't how to get the `venues/explore` endpoint (which accepts the `sortByDistance` parameter which I need to pass).

How do I get `venues/explore` on Sharpsquare? Does it have a different name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging deeper into Sharpsquare's code, it seems that the method was commented out. I've uncommented it but it had some work. There was a problem with the model mapping (for some reason it didn't map to the strongly typed model while everything seemed perfectly fitting). I've heavily messed with the internals until I got it working for my case, which might have destroyed something else (it didn't affect me as I'm not using something else anyway).

There's something broken with the model mapping (as the response of the endpoint is a bit different from endpoints), and that's probably why there has been code for the endpoint but has been commented out (as it's not working).